# SQL Server : Debit Card Conditional Transactions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, window-functions

I work for a telecommunications company that offers multiple packages to our customers. Some of those packages include having a set number of free long-distance minutes they can use each month.

Currently, the free minutes packages have a flaw in them that allows the customer to get way more free minutes than the package really allows. At the same time, the current system can sometimes prevent the customer from being able to use up all their free minutes in the right order.

I've already figured out how to modify the process to make sure the packages are being properly assigned to the customer's call records. Now, I'm trying to alter the way we process these records to prevent them from using more than is in their free minutes package.

I'm trying to solve this issue using a combination of CTEs, window functions, and update statements. The idea is that a customer with a free minutes package can use that package like a debit card so that if the call duration is less than the amount of minutes they have left, it covers the call and subtracts the amount of minutes left from the amount of available free minutes; but it doesn't cover the call if the duration exceeds the number of available free minutes. I've gotten almost all of it figured out, but I'm stuck because I cannot figure out how to look up a value calculated in a previous row by a window function.

Here is an example of the results that I am getting using my test table (note: Duration is in seconds, so it gets converted to minutes):

```
CustID  Duration    FrMinsAvailable NewAvMins   MinutesBilled   PrevAvMins
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
14000   250000      4250.2          83.5        4166.7          NULL
14000   9000        4250.2          -66.5       150             83.5
14000   4800        4250.2          -146.5      80              -66.5
14000   450         4250.2          -154        7.5             -146.5
14000   335         4250.2          -159.6      5.6             -154
14000   200         4250.2          -162.9      3.3             -159.6
14000   65          4250.2          -164        1.1             -162.9
14000   45          4250.2          -164.7      0.8             -164
14000   32          4250.2          -165.3      0.5             -164.7
14000   25          4250.2          -165.7      0.4             -165.3
14000   21          4250.2          -166        0.4             -165.7
14000   5           4250.2          -166.1      0.1             -166
```

Here is the result I would like to obtain:

```
CustID      Duration    FrMinsAvailable NewAvMins   MinutesBilled   PrevAvMins
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14000       250000      4250.2          83.5        4166.7          NULL
14000       9000        4250.2          83.5        150             83.5
14000       4800        4250.2          3.5         80              83.5
14000       450         4250.2          3.5         7.5             3.5
14000       335         4250.2          3.5         5.6             3.5
14000       200         4250.2          0.2         3.3             3.5
14000       65          4250.2          0.2         1.1             0.2
14000       45          4250.2          0.2         0.8             0.2
14000       32          4250.2          0.2         0.5             0.2
14000       25          4250.2          0.2         0.4             0.2
14000       21          4250.2          0.2         0.4             0.2
14000       5           4250.2          0.1         0.1             0.2
```

Finally, here is the test code I was using:

```
DECLARE @testDuration TABLE (CustID INT, Duration INT)

INSERT INTO @testDuration(CustID, Duration)
VALUES (14005, 65), (14005, 200), (14005, 4800), (14005, 25),
       (14005, 5), (14005, 450), (14005, 21), (14005, 32),
       (14005, 335), (14005, 45), (14005, 9000), (14005, 250000);

WITH my_cte AS 
(
    SELECT
        d.CustID,
        d.Duration,
        fm.FrMinsAvailable,
        ROUND((fm.FrMinsAvailable-SUM(CAST(d.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60)
                OVER (PARTITION BY d.CustID ORDER BY d.Duration DESC)), 1) NewAvMins,
        ROUND((CAST(d.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60), 1) BillMins
    FROM 
        (SELECT '14000' CustID, '4250.2' FrMinsAvailable) fm
    INNER JOIN 
        @testDuration   ON fm.CustID = d.SerialNoID
    GROUP BY 
        d.CustID, d.Duration, fm.FrMinsAvailable
)
SELECT 
    my_cte.*,
    (LAG(my_cte.NewAvMins) OVER (PARTITION BY my_cte.CustID ORDER BY my_cte.Duration DESC)) PrevAvMins
FROM 
    my_cte
```

What I ultimately intend to do is to use these results to set a value that allows the customer to get free minutes for that call where MinutesBilled <= PrevAvMins.  If you're asking why I don't just create a bunch of tables to accomplish this, it's really that I'm trying to reduce the load on the server running this process by minimizing reads and writes because the whole procedure to process all the records received each day already involves a lot of records, takes several hours to complete, and the server has other procedures to run, as well.

The solution doesn't have to involve window functions and CTEs, but that was the best solution I came up with.  I'd really appreciate some good feedback! :)

Thanks!

P.S. I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: `SELECT '14005' CustID, '4250.2' FrMinsAvailable` and also `ON fm.CustID = d.CustID`

Comment: have a look at the `LEAD()` and `LAG()` functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @TJB I'm using LAG at the end of the code to get PrevAvMins.  I could use it inside the CTE, but the issue is that it apparently cannot access a field calculated by a window function; for instance, it won't let me do `LAG(NewAvMins) OVER (PARTITION BY d,CustID ORDER BY d.Duration DESC))`.  Do you know of a way I could get LAG to access that field?

Comment: @edze Actually, the SELECT statement there actually replaced a table name I was using.  I did that so someone could simply copy-paste my code and get it to work on their end without needing the table. lol

Comment: Ap0ologies so you have, I have posted a solution for you as an answer using `sum over()`

Answer (score 0):

You need the to use `SUM OVER()` to achive a cumulative total, please see below working of your code:

```
DECLARE @testDuration TABLE (CustID INT, Duration decimal (18,0))
INSERT INTO @testDuration(CustID, Duration)
    VALUES  
        (14005, 65)
        , (14005, 200)
        , (14005, 4800)
        , (14005, 25)
        , (14005, 5)
        , (14005, 450)
        , (14005, 21)
        , (14005, 32)
        , (14005, 335)
        , (14005, 45)
        , (14005, 9000)
        , (14005, 250000);

        if object_id('tempdb..#callRecords') is not null
            drop table #callRecords;

        select td.CustID, Duration,4250.2 as FrAvailableMinutes
        into #callRecords
        from @testDuration as td;

        with cte as (

        select cr.CustID
             , cr.Duration
             , cr.FrAvailableMinutes 
             , row_number() over (partition by cr.CustID order by duration asc) as CallDateKey
             from #callRecords as cr
             )

             select cte.CustID
                  , cte.Duration
                  , cte.FrAvailableMinutes
                  , cte.CallDateKey
                  , round(sum(Duration) over (order by CallDateKey rows between unbounded preceding and current row)/60,2) as CumulativeDUration
                  , cte.FrAvailableMinutes - round(sum(Duration) over (order by CallDateKey rows between unbounded preceding and current row)/60,2) as MinutesLeft

            from cte
            order by CallDateKey desc
```

**Edit:** Further to your comment below, I have also provided a loop solution for your business requirement:

```
declare @testDuration table
    (
        CustID int
      , Duration decimal(18, 0)
      , CallDateKey int
    );
insert into @testDuration
     (
         CustID
       , Duration
       , CallDateKey
     )
values
    (14005, 65, 1)
  , (14005, 200, 2)
  , (14005, 4800, 3)
  , (14005, 25, 4)
  , (14005, 5, 5)
  , (14005, 450, 6)
  , (14005, 21, 7)
  , (14005, 32, 8)
  , (14005, 335, 9)
  , (14005, 45, 10)
  , (14005, 9000, 11)
  , (14005, 250000, 12)
  , (14005, 500, 13);

if object_id('tempdb..#Billing') is not null
    drop table #Billing;

create table #Billing
    (
        CustId int
      , Duration decimal(18, 0)
      , FrAvailableSeconds decimal(18, 2)
      , CallDateKey int
      , CumulativeDuration decimal(18, 2)
      , SecondsLeft decimal(18, 2)
    );

with CallRecords
    (CustID, DUration, CallDateKey, FrAvailableSeconds)
as (
       select td.CustID
            , Duration
            , td.CallDateKey
            , 4250.20 * 60
       from @testDuration as td
   )
insert into #Billing
     (
         CustId
       , Duration
       , FrAvailableSeconds
       , CallDateKey
       , CumulativeDuration
       , SecondsLeft
     )
select cr.CustID
     , cr.DUration
     , cr.FrAvailableSeconds
     , cr.CallDateKey
     , round(   sum(DUration) over (order by
                                        CallDateKey
                                    rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                                   ) / 60
              , 2
            )
     , cr.FrAvailableSeconds
from CallRecords as cr;


declare @a int = (
                     select min(CustId) from #Billing as b
                 );
declare @b int = (
                     select max(CustId) from #Billing as b
                 );

declare @x int;
declare @y int;

while @a <= @b
begin

    set @x = (
                 select min(b.CallDateKey) from #Billing as b where b.CustId = @a
             );
    set @y = (
                 select max(b.CallDateKey) from #Billing as b where b.CustId = @a
             );

    while @x <= @y
    begin


        update b
        set b.SecondsLeft = case
                                when isnull(ps.SecondsLeft, b.FrAvailableSeconds) - b.Duration < 0 then
                                    isnull(ps.SecondsLeft, b.FrAvailableSeconds)
                                else
                                    isnull(ps.SecondsLeft, b.FrAvailableSeconds) - b.Duration
                            end
        from #Billing as b
        left join (
                      select b.CustId
                           , SecondsLeft
                      from #Billing as b
                      where
                          b.CallDateKey = @x - 1
                          and b.CustId = @a
                  ) as ps
            on b.CustId = ps.CustId
        where
            b.CustId = @a
            and b.CallDateKey = @x;

        set @x += 1;

    end;

    set @a += 1;



end;

select b.CustId
     , b.Duration
     , b.FrAvailableSeconds
     , b.FrAvailableSeconds / 60 as FrAvailableMinutes
     , b.CallDateKey
     , b.CumulativeDuration
     , b.SecondsLeft
     , b.SecondsLeft / 60 as MinutesLeft
from #Billing as b
order by
    b.CallDateKey desc;
```

Comment: This doesn't quite accomplish what I'm looking for.  The issue is that I need to be able to only subtract the call duration from the minutes left when the call duration is less or equal to the minutes left.  If the call duration is greater than the minutes left, it should equal the previous calculation for minutes left (basically, minutes left won't change) or I need to be able to exclude that record from the window calculation.

Comment: How big is the data set, because you might be looking at some sort of loop for this?

Comment: I've added a loop solution.

Comment: Currently, we process about 500,000 to 700,000 records on most days.
I think you might be right, though - the best way to process them through this part of the script may be to simply loop each record through a codeblock.  I was hoping I could solve it in a better way.  I'm worried that a loop will have a large impact on performance because it would involve a lot more I/O activity than a window function, but we may have no other choice.

Comment: You won't be able to use a windowed function because it does not calculate according to the result of the previous row's context, but within its own row context, so a loop will be necessary (you can try the loop in my edited answer).

Comment: I read into this and found that in order to be able to accomplish what I'm trying to do using window functions, I would probably have to use "comparative window functions", which can theoretically be implemented into SQL Server, but it hasn't yet and, perhaps, never will be.  This is mentioned in Microsoft SQL Server 2014 High-Performance T-SQL Using Window Functions by Itzik Ben-Gan.  It looks interesting because it would add a whole new level of functionality to window functions.

Thanks for looking at this issue, though.  If I find a solution, I'll try to remember to post it here.